# Generate Ethereum address with private key

Tags: web3js, wallets, nodejs, private-key, public-key

How can I generate ethereum account address and private key that works on ethereum main network using web3 in nodejs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple,

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/Your API key here#"));

async function createAccount(){
    var wallet = await web3.eth.accounts.create();
    console.log('Address:' + wallet.address);
    console.log('Private Key: ' + wallet.privateKey)
}

createAccount();
```

And run this js file in the console using `node filename.js`. You will get what you want.